# Convert word document to PDF in flutter from a blob object

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, mobile, blob

I am getting a word document from an API request as blob then i to a unit8list to show the PDF in the pdfviewer how can i convert it in Flutter so i can i just give the widget pdfViewer the api response and it will show the converted PDF file from doc or docx

you can help me even better if you can show me a flutter widget that can accept a word document as a blob object this will be more efficient but i saw all the libraries that would help me are either Paid and i want the free version or i need to download the file on the machine to show the word document

i tried to change the file extension but it did not work